# How do I make a third id property appear?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have 2 dropdownlist and a textbox.  I managed to do a function that upon selection of a certain value in the first dropdownlist, the 2nd dropdownlist appears.  But I am unable to make the 3rd id (the textbox) appears where it reacts to the 2nd dropdownlist.

Here's what I have so far

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        change($("#<%=ddlMailJob.ClientID%>"));

        $("#<%=ddlMBR.ClientID%>").change(function () {
            change($(this));
        });
    });

    function change(obj) {
        if ($(obj).val() == "Y") {
            $('#lblMBRY').show();
            $('#ddlMBRY').show();
        }
        else {
            $('#lblMBRY').hide();
            $('#ddlMBRY').hide();

            $('#lblMBRO').hide();
            $('#txtMBRO').hide();
        }
    }
```

I want to make the

`$('#lblMBRO').hide();
$('#txtMBRO').hide();`

appears upon selection of the 2nd dropdownlist, but I have no idea how I should approach it.  The value that make it appears should be "Others"

Sorry.  Here's my html

```
                <td>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlMBR" runat="server">
                    <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="empty">- - -</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="Y">Yes</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="N">No</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </td>

            <td class="colHead" id="lblMBRY">Mailing Job</td>
            <td id="ddlMBRY">
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlMailJob" runat="server">
                    <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="empty">- - -</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="dlv">Deliver</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="pck">Pickup</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="Others">Others</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </td>

            <td class="colHead" id="lblMBRO">Others</td>
            <td id="txtMBRO">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtOther" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
```

Comment: ok nd your html looks like?

Comment: you probably want to avoid calling it change since there is already a function named change. You should call it something that doesn't already exist like changeVisible(obj)

Comment: Another minor point: you're passing a jquery object to the function (`change($(this));`) so no need to wrap it in jquery again: `if ($(obj).val() == "Y") {` can be `if (obj.val() == "Y") {`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you didnt provide your html, I created sample html and script for that. MAy be this can help you
Html

```
<select id="first">
   <option value="">Select</option>
   <option value="Y">yes</option>
   <option value="N">no</option>
</select>
<select class="slct" id="second">
   <option value="">Select</option>
   <option value="Y">yes</option>
   <option value="N">no</option>
</select>
<select class="slct" id="third">
   <option value="">Select</option>
   <option value="Y">yes</option>
   <option value="N">no</option>
</select>
```

Script

```
$(".slct").hide();
$("select").change(function () {

  if ($("#first").val() == "Y") 
    {

      $("#second").show();
      if ($("#second").val() == "Y")
      {

        $("#third").show();
      }
      else
      {
         $("#third").hide();
      }
    } 
  else
  {
      $(".slct").hide();
  }
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/YVHNe/4/)

Comment: Please fix your code indentation so it doesn't look so confusing to understand the code's intent.